# Probability of cars being blocked during red light

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Given one lane for turning left and one lane for thru traffic. Cars arrive according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 20$ per minute. An arriving car turns left with ${40\%}$ probability, and wants to go straight with 60% probability. The left-hand turn lane has a max capacity of $10$ cars. If more than $10$ cars arrive when the light is red ($1$ minute long), then the cars wanting to turn left block the progress of cars wanting to go straight.

a. During the $1$-minute period when the light is red, what is the probability that the left-hand turn lane blocks progress of cars wanting to go straight?

b. Given that $11$ left-turning cars have arrived during the $1$-minute period when the light is red, what is the probability that no through-cars are blocked during this period?

**My thought** **(a)** is simple. We could denote $X =$ number of cars arrive on the left-hand turn lane during red line where $X\sim $ PP$(20\times 0.4 = 8)$. Thus $P(X\geq 11) = 1-P(X=0) - P(X=1) -\cdots - P(X=10) = 1- e^{-8} - e^{-8}*8 - \cdots e^{-8}\frac{8^{10}}{10!} = 0.112.$

**(b)** I could only see that since $11$ left-turning cars have arrived already, there are no through cars blocked if and only if there are no cars arriving going straight during that $1$-minute period. Thus, $P(N(1) = 0) = e^{-12}$.

**My question** I'm not sure if my thought for part (b) is correct, since the problem seems to be tricky. Could anyone please help review my solution above and give some thoughts? Would really appreciate any input.

Comment: Just a thought that in (a) shouldn't you multiply that P(a car wanting to go straight comes after left lane has >= 10 cars) ?

Comment: Also in (b) we shouldn't directly calculate the probability of having no straight car in the one minute because during whole one minute the straight way is not blocked. It gets blocked only when the left lane has >= 11 cars.

Comment: @Alvis: for (b), we are given the left lane has $\geq 11$ cars already, so that's the only possibility I could think of. Don't quite get what you meant.

Comment: in (b) my issue is that suppose that 11th car going in left comes at 30th second in one case and 60th second in another. Then in first case u have 30 seconds for the some straight car to get blocked but in second you dont have anytime when a straight car is blocked.

Comment: @Alvis: great observation! So you meant we need to add $P($11th car arrives at the 60th second$) = e^{-8}$? I'm not quite sure how to compute this probability though.


For part (a), you are correct, except that we need to multiple by $P($ AT LEAST $1$ car wanting to go straight comes after the 11th car has arrived on the left lane during the $1$-minute period$)$. This is equal to  $1-$P(0$ cars wanting to go straight after the 11th arrive on the left-land during the 1-minute period) ? But how could we compute this?

Comment: @Alvis: for $(a)$, I got $0.112\times (20\times 0.4)/(8+12)$ as a result, where the $0.112$ is what I computed in the original post, and the remaining factor remains from the fact that the inter-arrival time $T_{11}, T_{12}$ of each of these poisson processes follow exponential distribution, and we want $P(T_{12}>T_{11})$.

$For (b)$, did you get $8e^{-8}+e^{-12}$ as a result, where $8e^{-8}$ comes from the fact that the $11$th car arrived right at the 60th second on the left-lane.

Comment: Could anyone please help me with this problem? It's quite annoying to compute the probability correctly, even though from Alvis's feedback, I know exactly what I need to compute:P I don't think my result in my last comment was correct.