# Variance of total number of customers arriving

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose a customer arrival to a gas station follows a non-stationary Poisson process with the following arrival rate per hour:

- [6am - 9am] has $\lambda = 20$.
- [9am - 3pm] has $\lambda = 8$.
- [3pm - 7pm] has $\lambda = 12$.
- [7pm - 10pm] has $\lambda = 6$.

Compute the variance of total number of customers that arrive in a single day.

**My attempt** Let $X = $ total number of customers that arrive in a single day. Then $Var(X) = E(X^2)- [E(X)]^2 = (20^2\times 3+8^2\times 6+12^2\times 4 + 6^2\times 3) -  (20\times 3+8\times 6+12\times 4 + 6\times 3)^2 = 2268-174^2 = -28008$

However, this number is negative, so it does not make sense in the context of this problem. But I could not see why it's wrong though, considering the way to compute $E(X)$ is actually correct. Could someone please point out the mistake for $E(X^2)$?

Comment: Your expressions for $E(X^2)$ contain an error, though I think one of the numbers you have written down is the answer

Comment: @Henry: really? Why $[E(X)]^2$ is wrong? Could you elaborate on your thought?

Comment: Originally you forgot to square $E(X)$.  Your subsequent edit corrected that.

Comment: But then why $E(X^2)$ has error then? I could not see:p could you be clearer please?

Comment: Your method might suggest that a Poisson distribution with $\lambda=20$ had $E(X^2)=20^2$ and so its variance would be $20^2-(20)^2=0$

Comment: I see. So maybe I would have to use conditional variance formula then?

Comment: No - the variance of a Poisson distribution is $\lambda$ so it has $E(X^2)=\lambda+\lambda^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two key points:

1. A Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ (i.e. its mean and variance) has $E(X^2)=\lambda+\lambda^2$: this is the error in your calculation as you were using $E(X^2)=\lambda^2$
2. The sum of two independent Poisson distributions with parameters  $\lambda$ and $\mu$ is another Poisson distribution with parameter  $\lambda+\mu$

So you have $16$ independent Poisson distributions and their sum is another Poisson distribution with parameter  $20\times 3+8\times 6+12\times 4 + 6\times 3 =174$. This is therefore the variance of the sum as well as being its mean.

Comment: many thanks man! My key problem was I did not realize the final process is Poisson:) Could you also give this problem a try? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929973/probability-of-cars-being-blocked-during-red-light

Answer (score 1):

You have a Poisson process $N(t)$ on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Let X=N(16), i.e. the total number of customers in a single 16-hour day.

You want to use that $Y_1=N(3)-N(0)$, $Y_2=N(9)-N(3)$, $Y_3=N(13)-N(9)$ and $Y_4=N(16)-N(13)$ are **independent** and each $\text{Poisson}(\lambda_i)$-distributed, where

$\lambda_1 = 3\cdot 20=60, \lambda_2 = 6 \cdot 8 = 48, \lambda_3 = 4 \cdot 12 = 48, \lambda_4 = 3 \cdot 6 = 18$.

For a Poisson-distributed random variable $M$ with parameter $\lambda_M$, $\text{Var}(M)=\mathbb{E}[M]=\lambda_M$.

Now $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y_1+Y_2+Y_3+Y_4]=\sum_{i=1}^4 \mathbb{E}[Y_i]=\sum_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i$, and due to independence,

$\text{Var}(X)=\text{Var}(Y_1+Y_2+Y_3+Y_4)=\sum_{i=1}^4 \text{Var}(Y_i) = \sum_{i=1}^4 \mathbb{E}[Y_i] = \mathbb{E}[X]$.

Comment: I know, that I did not directly answer your question. I think the important part of the problem is the idea of splitting it into different periods - so I tried to point you in that direction instead.

Comment: Excellent help! Many thanks, Furrer. I see what I got wrong now:)

Comment: Wonderful! The result might at first seem counter-intuitive - shouldn't different periods with different arrival rates yield a higher variance than a constant arrival rate throughout the whole day, one could ask. But that is where the independent increments of the Poisson process come into play. Therefore I think the  problem you stated here is excellent to keep in mind if one is considering to build some model using the Poisson process.