# Prove that if $X$ is standard normal then $|X|$ and $1_{X>0}$ are independent

Tags: probability-theory

> Given $X$ is standard Normal distributed ($X\sim N(0,1)$). Show that $|X|$ and $1_{X>0}$ are independent.

**My attempt** $|X| = X$ for $X>0$, and $|X| = -X$ for $X\leq 0$. Each of these possibilities have $p=\frac{1}{2}$ as $X$ ~ $N(0,1)$. Same probabilities work for $1_{X>0} = 1$ for $X>0$ and $0$ for $X<0$. But now, we need to find $P(|X|\cap 1_{X>0})$. This intersection turns out to be $1$ if $X>0$, and $0$ if $X\leq 0$.

We have: $P(1) = P(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ (by definition of $1_{X>0}$). But $\frac{1}{2}$ is not equal to $P(X)P(1)$ for $X>0$ or $X\leq 0$, isn't it?

**My question** I think I messed up something here on the product of the two probabilities. Could someone please help correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must show $$P(|X| \leq a, \mathbf{1}_{X > 0} \leq b) = P(|X| \leq a)P(\mathbf{1}_{X > 0} \leq b).$$

I'll sketch the case $0 \leq b <1$. The other cases should be easy.

Start by just thinking about what the events mean. The event $\{|X| \leq a, \mathbf{1}_{X > 0} \leq b)\}$ is equivalent to $\{|X| \leq a, \mathbf{1}_{X>0} = 0  \} = \{ -a \leq X \leq a, X \leq 0 \} = \{-a \leq X \leq 0\}$.

Now we can calculate the probabilities using the density $\phi$ of the standard normal.

$$ P(|X| \leq a, \mathbf{1}_{X > 0} \leq b) = P(-a \leq X \leq 0) = \int_{-a}^{0}\phi(x)dx = 1/2 \int_{-a}^{a}\phi(x)dx   $$

Notice that we've used the symmetry of $\phi$. On the other hand we also have

$$P(|X| \leq a)P(\mathbf{1}_{X > 0} \leq b) = \int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx \int_{-\infty}^{0} \phi(x)dx = 1/2 \int_{-a}^{a}\phi(x)dx,$$

where we use the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^{0} \phi(x)dx = 1/2$.

Comment: great help. Many thanks. I just want to confirm: for the case when either $a\leq 0$ or $b<0$, both sides of the equation are equal since they are both equal to $0$? And also, for $b\geq 1$, both sides $=\int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx$?

Btw, could you please help give this problem a try: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929973/probability-of-cars-being-blocked-during-red-light

Comment: @user177196 Yep, that's right.

Comment: did you have a chance to try the other problem in the link?

Answer (score 2):

Proving two random variables are independent is a bit different than proving two events are independent. Quoting Wikipedia,

> Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if for every $a$ and $b$, the two events $\{X \leq a\}$ and $\{Y \leq b\}$ are independent.

And, again, quoting Wikipedia,

> Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if their joint probability equals the product of their probabilities, $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$.

So, now, using these definitions, to answer your question we need to show that for every $a$ and $b$, $P(|X| \leq a \cap 1_{X > 0} \leq b) = P(|X| \leq a) P(1_{X > 0} \leq b)$.

See if you can transfer your work done so far to these definitions.

Comment: Please use this definition in your answer.

Comment: I think the definition is implicit in the equation after "We must show"

Comment: Seeing that the OP's thoughts led them to the nonsensical $$\text{"we need to find $P(|X|\cap 1_{X>0})$"}$$ I do not feel that this answer is offtopic. In a way, this is even the most proper answer one can imagine.

Comment: @Did: my apology for making a dumb statement:P But I got it now, thanks to aduh and ahmedb's help, so really appreciate that. Could you please help with this problem Sir: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929973/probability-of-cars-being-blocked-during-red-light.

I'm not quite sure my final answer for part (a) (in the comment) is correct, even after a lengthy discussion with another member here. For part (b), I'm not sure if computing P(N(1)=12) is a right way to go, even though i know exactly what needs to be computed:(